# Form's TextBox not updating, but ProgressBar is in ProgressChanged()

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

Trying to update a UI element that updates as DoWork() iterates through every line in a DataTable with a visual progress bar and a textbox that gives the current value. The iteration happens in a background worker and works as expected, as does the progress bar's PerformStep(). However, the TextBox's Text does not change.

```
    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        table = SegmentationLibrary.Core.Utils.GetTableFromQuery(query);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(table.Rows.Count, "Max");
        int status = 0;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(status);
        table.Columns.Add("seg_rates_id", typeof(Int32));
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            row["seg_rates_id"] = 0;
            status++;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(status);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

Progress:

```
    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.UserState != null && e.UserState.ToString() == "Max") {
            progressBar.progressBar1.Maximum = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
        else if (e.ProgressPercentage == 0)
        {
            progressBar.progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar.progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
            progressBar.progressBar1.Value = 1;
            progressBar.progressBar1.Step = 1;
            progressBar.tbProgress.Text = "Setting initial rate types";
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar.progressBar1.PerformStep();
            progressBar.tbProgress.Text = "Current at row " + progressBar.progressBar1.Value + " of " + progressBar.progressBar1.Maximum + ", " + progressBar.GetProgressBarPercent().ToString() + "%.";
        }
    }
```

Caller:

```
    public void GetFinacData(int year, int month)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            currentMonth = month;
            currentYear = year;

            query = "SELECT * FROM FINAC_ACTUAL_DATA WHERE fiscal_year = " +
                currentYear + " AND fiscal_month = " + currentMonth + ";";
            progressBar.Show();
            progressBar.progressBarStyle = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            progressBar.tbProgress.Text = "Downloading PSGL Extract from database";
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

            // required for ProgressBar to update?
            while (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                Application.DoEvents();

            workerCompleted.WaitOne();
            progressBar.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Segmentation already in progress.","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

What's happening:

[image]

I tried a few different things, but none of them work. Adding another DoEvents() at the end of ProgressChanged causes a stack overflow. Any ideas?

Comment: Never use `DoEvents()` unless you have a *complete* understanding of how the application event/message loop works.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx

Comment: I would highly suggest you remove all `DoEvents()` calls, and see go from there.

Comment: @roryap I've now removed all the DoEvents() and use Invalidate()/Update() on the progressBar. This worked and solved my problem. However, there was a Marquee that scrolled during the GetTableFromQuery() (takes around 30 seconds) that is no longer scrolling. Definitely helped though, so thanks. :)

Comment: You are firehosing the UI thread.  If you have no clue how to do it properly then simply add Thread.Sleep(45) after the ReportProgress() call.

Comment: @HansPassant I replied to your initial comment (gone now?) which was very helpful. I fixed the refresh to only update every 25 rows, and removed the DoEvents() so now the initial problem is gone. However, now the marquee is now blocked during the GetTableFromQuery(). Removing the DoEvents() also did make everything else a lot more responsive, so that's good.

Comment: The `workerCompleted.WaitOne();` line at the bottom of `GetFinacData` is seriously bad mojo when run from the UI thread (which it appears to be).  Use the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to signal other parts of the program that things are complete.  It's possible to leave it there if you use the newer [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) constructs.

Answer (score 1):

you could wrap you ui changing code inside this code

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* ui changing code */ }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the updating from the background work, not from your main thread. At this point your main thread is still working and your updates are not processed.

remove

```
        // required for ProgressBar to update?
        while (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            Application.DoEvents();

        workerCompleted.WaitOne();
        progressBar.Hide();
```

then move the:

```
       progressBar.Hide();
```

to the end of your background worker. And remove all DoEvents from your code. It is not needed to do the updates.